# After Refresh Cant fetch user details oAuth (passport npm)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, passport.js

CURRENT SCENARIO

Once I log in via social auth it shows the **username** and **provider** detail on the page. but if I refresh again it shows the error. I am sending the user object via render but still, it doesn't fetch the details. I don't understand why.

```js
{"error":{"message":"Failed to fetch user profile"}}
```

Below is my express session snippet in my app.js file

```js
app.use(expressSession({
    name: 'Session',
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    secret: [keys.session.cookieKey],
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true

}))
app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
```

Below is my oauth.js file

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport')

router.get('/login',(req, res, next) => {
    //create a func where we check if the user logged in then show the profile page , if not logged in then show login page
    res.render('login')
});

router.get('/logout', (req, res, next) => {
    req.session = null
    req.logout()
    res.redirect('/')
});

router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope: ['profile']
}));
router.get('/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    scope: ['profile']
}));

router.get('/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter', {
    scope: ['profile']
}));

router.get('/github', passport.authenticate('github', {
    scope: ['profile']
}));


router.get('/google/redirect', passport.authenticate('google', {
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}), (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('profile', {
        user: req.user
    })
});

router.get('/facebook/redirect', passport.authenticate('facebook', {
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}), (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('profile', {
        user: req.user
    })
});
router.get('/twitter/redirect', passport.authenticate('twitter', {
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}), (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('profile', {
        user: req.user
    })
});

router.get('/github/redirect', passport.authenticate('github', {
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}), (req, res, next) => {
    console.log('user details: '+req.user)
    res.render('profile', {
        user: req.user
    })

});





module.exports = router;
```

Comment: the code looks fine. but i would suggest if you could use res.redirect in the redirect call instead of res.render and check if the issue still persists

Comment: @MohitTilwani login is a ejs script for rendering the login page.